# Game: two stacks of coins and reducing by divisor of number of coins on the stack

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, contest-math, game-theory

> Player $A$ and $B$ play a game: There are two stacks of coins, first stack has $a=12$ coins, second - has $b=8$ coins. Each player choose a stack and remove $d$ coins, if choose first stack $d|a$, otherwise $d|b.$ Player win if other player can't move. Which player has a winning strategy?
>
> How change the answer if $a=20,b=28$?

I know answer by trials if $a=5,b=3$ - $B$ has winning strategy: this player take one coin from this stack, which was choosed by $A$ at last move, if it is possible. If it isn't possible, it means that $A$ get last coin on the stack.

I have problem to see a general pattern. I thought that in situation that $a=12,b=8$ $B$ get not one coin, but $gcd(12,8)=4$ coins by analogy to situation described above; I don't see at moment any reason.

Comment: How much do you know about combinatorial game theory, specifically impartial games, Nim, and the Sprague-Grundy Theorem?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find the solution, though I cannot explain how unless you are familiar with combinatorial game theory.

A position $(a,b)$ is either a win for the first or second player. If exactly one of $a$ or $b$ is zero, then the position is a first player win, and the winning move consists of reducing the nonzero stack to zero.

Otherwise, let $v(a)$ be the largest power of two dividing into $a$. For example, $v(20)=4, v(120)=8, v(16)=16, v(\text{any odd number})=1$.

> **Theoerm:** If $a,b>0$, the game $(a,b)$ is a win for the first player if and only $v(a)\neq v(b)$.
>   If $v(a)>v(b)$, then a winning strategy is to decrease $a$ by $v(b)$.
>   If $v(a)<v(b)$, then a winning strategy is to decrease $b$ by $v(a)$.

When $(a,b)=(12,8)$, then $v(a)=4$ and $v(b)=8$, so this position is a win for the first player. A winning move is to decrease $8$ by $4$, resulting in the position $(8,8)$.

When $(a,b)=(20,28)$, then $v(a)=4$ and $v(b)=4$, so this position is a loss for the first player. This means every move for the first player has a winning response: for example, if the first player removes $4$ from the first stack, leaving $(16,28)$, then the second player would respond by removing $v(28)=4$ from the $16$ stack, leaving $(12,28)$.

To prove the Theorem, you just need to show two things. Call a position *equalized* if $v(a)=v(b)$.

- If a position is not equalized, then performing the move described above equalizes it.
- If a position is equalized, then any move will leave it unequalized.

I leave these proofs to the reader.

---

As to how I found this strategy; the two stack game is the *sum* of two one-stack games. You can compute the *Grundy values* of a one-stack game recursively by making a table, and for each entry letting the value be the *mex* of the values of that number minus its divisors. After doing that I saw a pattern and proved it. I do not now how I would have seen the pattern without familiarity with the *italicized* concepts.

Comment: Nice!  And very Nimish---writing $a$ in binary, $v(a)$ can be gotten reading right to left until the first 1 is found.

Comment: Help:  To clarify the game: If you have the position (5,3), can you get to (2,3)? Do the substraction have to be a divisor of the number you are substracting or of the other? Because I believe its the other, because I solved for "of the other" and got the same answer as you, however the questioner then I believe wrote his problem wrong when he says "Each player choose a stack and remove d coins, if choose first stack d|a, otherwise d|b. Player win if other player can't move. Which player has a winning strategy?"

Comment: @Santropedro I answered the question assuming the subtraction is a division of the size of the pile you are taking from. I see no reason to believe the questioner is wrong. Do you think that my answer is incorrect for this variant?

Comment: @MikeEarnest I did't think it was incorrect at any moment, before or now. However, I now understand a little bit better. What happens, is that the strategy you found, believe or not, works in almost the exact same way, and the winning and loosing positions are the exact same, in this variant: same thing, but now (as I suggested before) you take from a pile a divisor of the OPPOSITE pile, in this alternative game, you can go for example from $(5,3)$ to $(2,3)$ in one move, unlike in your game. Same strategy works, with the same proof basically speaking.

Comment: @Santropedro Interesting observation! Different rules, same outcome... coincidence? Or hidden symmetry?